# CMake : Include subdirectories

Tags: include, cmake, subdirectory

I have currently, in my CMake lists :

```
FIND_PATH(BOINC_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES boinc_api.h
      PATH_SUFFIXES boinc
      DOC "The Boinc include directory (where boinc_api.h is)")
```

This command find the directory /usr/include/boinc.
But I want to add all the subdirectories in the boinc directory.
How to do that ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code. It iterates through all files and directories in BOINC_INCLUDE_DIR and appends directories to include directories list:

```
FILE(GLOB _ALL_FILES ${BOINC_INCLUDE_DIR} ${BOINC_INCLUDE_DIR}/*)
FOREACH(_FILE ${_ALL_FILES})
  IF(IS_DIRECTORY ${_FILE})
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${_FILE})
  ENDIF()
ENDFOREACH()
```